Is there any way to select (i.e. create locators) by style value?
In Playwright there are a lot of ways to create locators, mostly involving CSS selectors. However, as far as I can tell, there's no way to say "find the red button" (i.e. the <button> with background-color: red).
If the button has a red class, then of course you can select .red, but what if you don't have a class? If you only care about certain styles (e.g. display) you can use special Playwright selectors (e.g. :visible), but they only work for those specific styles.
Is there any general purpose way to find elements based on any style value?

Why do you want to do this? As always, please provide context/motivation when asking something unusual. There's usually a better, more direct solution. This isn't considered a good idea, even if possible. Maybe you're looking to write a screenshot test? If the color string is literally "red", that's selectable with getComputedStyle(), or with CSS selectors if it's inline, but again, not recommended.

I would think it'd be self-evident why I'd want to locate (say) "the red button".

Interesting. If it's so self-evident, then why isn't it supported by basically any library I know of? I don't see this sort of question often. Even CSS selectors are considered poor practice in tests. There's this question but it's specific to style tag selection, which has a clear use case. In some web scraping contexts, the only way to disambiguate elements is the style prop.

It's not self-evident why you'd have no more stable way of identifying it than "the red one" - if that's the only way a user can identify it (no visible text, ARIA label, ...), it's potentially not very accessible, and even if that's acceptable in this context you can still make it more accessible to automation with e.g. data- properties.

Classes can change over time.  Button text can change over time.  When things change, your tests break.  Data attributes solve that, but tightly couple QA and Dev.  However, (as a simple example) a background-color of var(--mainColor) is extremely unlikely to change, barring a complete overhaul of the UI.  It also requires no coupling of Dev and QA ... so it seem like a far more maintainable option for certain cases.

@Machineghost Thanks for providing rationale. The problem with var(--mainColor) is that it's part of a stylesheet that browsers interpret. Browsers convert these to RGB strings for rendering and consider cascading styles from multiple sources, as well as inline and JS styles. I don't think there's an easy way to determine what CSS variable is applied to an element. Like I said, you can use getComputedStyle, but it's a loop over all the buttons in the document and expensive work. The established best practice is using aria role, which is even less likely to change than background color.

ARIAA roles let you indicate that something is a button, but they don't help distinguish the red from the blue button.  I still firmly believe selecting by style would have significant value ... but I also understand the technical limitations of selecting with them.  I just assumed that since the browser had the .style property and getComputedStyle, it wouldn't be that hard to loop over the elements in a locator and check each one.  If Playwright had a custom selector mechanism,  I'd imagine that I could write one myself.

@machineghost See my answer. It's not necessarily that hard to do it, and Playwright could have done something like this, but it's just not a good idea for all the reasons in my post (and probably others I haven't considered). Aria role selections distinguish by name, which is more important and more objective than color. It's OK that tests break if critical information like the text/value/name changes. You just update them to match the new text--that's the job of tests--reflecting and enforcing the page's specification. If the name isn't that important, then there are other ways to select.

There is no way I know of to do this out of the box, and I'm not sure that it's a good pattern.
Technically, something like this works:
import {test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button>Yellow</button>
<button>Blue</button>
<button>Red</button>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("button:last-of-type").style.color = "red";
}, 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>`;

test("red button eventually exists", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  const redButtonExists = `
    [...document.querySelectorAll("button")]
      .some(e => getComputedStyle(e).color === "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
  `;
  await page.waitForFunction(redButtonExists);
});

Problems:

This circumvents the standard selection best practices and functions provided by Playwright (and any other browser automation library I know of).

It's an expensive polling loop and getComputedStyle call.

"red" was converted by the browser to "rgb(255, 0, 0)", not something that's obvious (or necessarily guaranteed?). I haven't tested the behavior in other browsers, but it smells iffy.

Assertions like this aren't used often, so it's best to follow suit with standard selection practices.
Aria role is more stable and better practice. Test IDs would also be better, or selecting by text, value or attribute, or even a CSS attribute which is objective and doesn't pass through cascading styles and browser-specific interpretation.

Styles are generally pretty subjective and dynamic, so something like "find the red button" sounds logical to a human, but doesn't make a lot of sense in browser automation since there's no obvious definition of what "redness" entails, precisely, beyond the RGB definition.
An algorithm could give you a "close enough" reading--maybe that's what you're after. But that's just for color--the same problem exists for just about every other style. How rounded do rounded corners have to be to qualify? This seems like a deep pit of complexity and ambiguity with no obvious gain over established practices.

I can't imagine a test suite filled with "whack the red button, then hit the green one" would be anything but a headache to understand and maintain. Most sites with colored buttons have multiple buttons on the page with the same color, so to disambiguate between those, you're forced back in the standard role/name, text, test id, value, and attribute selection paradigm you tried to avoid.
First/last/nth are not considered good practice, because order is pretty arbitrary, so this isn't a way out of the problem.


In the above example, the best way to select the Red button is
const redButton = page.getByRole("button", {name: "Red", exact: true});
await expect(redButton).toBeVisible();

Consider that if the text changes and the test breaks, that's actually good. The goal is not to have a test suite that never breaks, but one that can be easily maintained to be in lockstep with the rendered reality and with the application's specification. (And text content is generally a critical part of a specification, arguably the most important thing on the page. A test suite that prefers enforcing colors and styles over the actual page content seems misguided. Think accessibility: what is the user experience for a blind person? Test that.)
You may be interested in screenshot tests, which implicitly assert colors of all elements within the screenshot area, but this assertion style has its own set of drawbacks and isn't a replacement for specific assertions on role, text and so forth.
If you only care about styles in style= attributes, see this thread. This has a clear use case: web scraping when there is no other way to distinguish a particular element. Tests should never touch style= attributes (and codebases you control shouldn't be using them in the first place).
Finally, there is a toHaveCSS assertion, but it doesn't quite work for your use case:
test("red button eventually exists", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await expect(page.getByRole("button")).toHaveCSS("color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
});

This fails with:
Error: expect.toHaveCSS: Error: strict mode violation: getByRole('button') resolved to 3 elements:
    1) <button>Yellow</button> aka getByRole('button', { name: 'Yellow' })
    2) <button>Blue</button> aka getByRole('button', { name: 'Blue' })
    3) <button>Red</button> aka getByRole('button', { name: 'Red' })

This assertion may be appropriate if you already have the element located and there's a good reason to test a particular CSS property.

You can only select specifically inline styles. In general, this isn't ideal though, since these values could be modified by style sheets and scripts. The more general effects you want cannot be achieved by CSS selectors. See the accepted answer (specifically the last two sentences) of CSS selector by inline style attribute
